# Rails patterns specific to web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, web-applications

I know about GoF and Rails patterns. But I am dying to learn more about common Rails patterns that apply specifically for web-app. For example, a SignUpPresenter would be great for a form that handle multiple models in one form. It took me about a month to realize this b/c I can't find a good source.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For patterns and anti-patterns I highly recommend [Rails AntiPatterns: Best Practice Ruby on Rails Refactoring](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321604814)

It's not all about patterns but you'll discover quite a few of them there.  This book is also quite an easy read.